# Remove the parenthesis area in a string pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying this:

There are also several countries with numbers and/or parenthesis in their name. Be sure to remove these,

e.g.

'Cuba (Island of Caribeas)' should be 'Cuba',

**DataFrame in**

```
    Country                         Energy    
18  Mexico                          321000000   
19  Cuba (Island of Caribeas)      102000000    
20  Algeria                        1959000000   
21  American                        2252661245  
22  Andorra(no mentioned)            9000000
```

**I would like to get this df (DF out)**

```
   Country                           Energy    
18  Mexico                          321000000   
19  Cuba                           102000000    
20  Algeria                        1959000000   
21  American                        2252661245  
22  Andorra                         9000000
```

**I am trying this**

```
for item in df['Country']: #remove the () with the data inside
   re.sub(r" ?\(\w+\)", "", item)
```

But I dont get any changes in my DF, and no error, so I dont know what I am doing wrong. Please someone could help me?

Comment: Could you please post a minimal reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression isn't quite right - what if there are white spaces in the brackets?

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['Cuba (Island of Caribeas)', 'Andorra(no mentioned)', 'Algeria'])

s.replace(r" ?\((?:\w+ ?)+\)", "", regex=True)
```

This will return:

```
Out[13]: 
0       Cuba
1    Andorra
2    Algeria
dtype: object
```

To adapt it to your example:

```
df['Country'] = df['Country'].replace(r" ?\((?:\w+ ?)+\)", "", regex=True)
```

Comment: r" ?\([^)]+\)", "", item I have fond this one, but you are right about the white spaces, thanks so much @ignoring_gravity

Answer (score 0):

This could be a start...
 try:

```
df['Country'] = df['Country'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r" ?\(\w+\)", "", x))
```

This will apply your expression to each value in df['Country']...

Comment: Thanks! but I continue getting the same problem, nothing change in the df. If I do the example I showed in the explanation, but in this case only for one row, this works, the problem is for all the rows of the column Country

Comment: I edited the comment...
Let me know if that doesn't change things, please.